# How to assign custom names to properties?

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I'm using a PLC shield (Kontron Pixtend) to read and control pneumatic valves and switches. A Python API (class) is provided. All runs on a Raspberry Pi. Outputs/inputs of the PLC shield are implemented using `@property` decorators:

```
class PiXtendV2L():
    ....
    @property
    def digital_in0(self):
        """
        Get the state of digital input 0. A value of False means 'off' and a value of True means 'on'.

        :return: Current value
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return self.test_bit(self._digital_in0, self.BIT_0) == 1

    @property
    def digital_in1(self):
        """
        Get the state of digital input 1. A value of False means 'off' and a value of True means 'on'.

        :return: Current value
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return self.test_bit(self._digital_in0, self.BIT_1) == 1

    @property
    def relay0(self):
        """
        Get or Set the state of relay 0. A value of False means 'off' and a value of True means 'on'.

        :return: Current value
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return self.test_bit(self._relay_out, self.BIT_0) == 1

    @relay0.setter
    def relay0(self, value):
        if value is False or value is True:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError("Value error!, Value " + str(value) + " not allowed! - Use only: False = off, True = on")

        bit_num = self.BIT_0
        if value is self.OFF:
            self._relay_out = self.clear_bit(self._relay_out, bit_num)
        if value is self.ON:
            self._relay_out = self.set_bit(self._relay_out, bit_num)
    ....
```

State of the relay is read accessing relay0 as variable, setting the relay by assigning True or False. I want to work with meaningful names:

```
self.p = PiXtendV2L(com_interval=0.05, callback=self.SPSCallback)
self.valve = self.p.relay0
self.switch = self.p.digital_in0

if self.switch:
    self.value = True
else:
    self.valve = False
```

I create `self.valve` and assign `self.p.relay0`. "relay0" is defined in PiXtendV2L class. But I cannot read state of the relay nor set it. It is not possible as the setter and getters are not accessed. I read the memory address of `print(id(self.switch)` and `print(id(self.p.relay0))` and get the same address. How can this be done without much code? The alternative is use the names from the PLC's lib (digital_in0, relay0, digital_out0, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want `switch` to be another name for `relay0` in your class then just add `switch = relay0` in your class somewhere after you've defined `relay0`.

If you want `switch` to have a little bit more smarts.

```
@property
def switch(self):
     do whatever you want, including accessing self.relay0
     return result

@switch.setter
def switch(self, value):
    do whatever you want, including setting self.relay0
```

Comment: thanks!
actually I want "valve" to be just another name for p.relay0
But "p.relay0" is implemented using the property decorator. 
So using "valve" instead of "p.relay0" does not work. Meaning when I do "p.relay0 = True" then the relay switches on. But if I do "value = True" nothing happens.
Also when I try to read the state of relay0 (e.g. print(p.relay0) then I get "True" when the relay is on, and "False" when the relay is off. But when using "print(valve)" I just get "False", even if the relay is actually on.

Comment: BTW: relay0 is defined in the PiXtendV2L class. That's the lib that comes with the PLC shield. And I'd really like to avoid changing this class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what causes a property's getter and setter method to be called is retrieving the attribute from the instance with the `.` notation.

If you try to simply assign the retrieved property from another instance to a plain variable, as you are doing - that will call the getter at assignment time, not when your result attribute is read.

Since you are doing this in a container class , that has an associated `PixtendV2L` instance, you can write properties in this container class that will call the original properties. (I am inferring you are writting a container class, since your snippet just show `self. ...` code at top level. I fyou had that class code, I could write the final code you will need.

```
def MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
         self.p = PiXtendV2L(com_interval=0.05, callback=self.SPSCallback)

    @property
    def valve(self):
        return self.p.relay0
    @valve.setter
    def valve(self, value):
        self.p.relay0 = value

    # or, it can be writen in a single line like this:
    # note that it is at class body-level, not inside a method
    switch = property(lambda s: s.p.digital_in0, lambda s, v: setattr(self.p, "digital_in0", v)

    ...

   def another_method(self):
      if self.switch:
         self.valve = True
      else:
         self.valve = False
```

(Note however, that this won't make `another_method` to be called on `switch` state change - not sure if the original class does that.